# Graphically link the principal nav bar with the secondary one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm tryig to build a responsive website. I'm at the first phase in which, according to the "content first" metodology, I must consider the smallest mobile layout. The homepage (under construction) is something like this:

[image: my homepage]

When the user clicks, for instance, on the first icon a secondary nav bar appears below the principal one. See this image (don't look at the icons, the images are random and temporary):

[image: homepage with secondary nav bar]

I would like graphically linking the two bars in some way. I don't know, maybe with an image like in these examples:

[image: example of link between bars]
[image: example2 of link between bars]

Is this a correct way to do this thing? And, also in the case that it was a good practice, how can I position the "link image" in a way independent from the screen width? The position has to be based on other elements position or, maybe, on percentages. It cannot be based on an absolute positioning. In this case, indeed, resizing the screen will make a mess like in the image below:

[image: resizing has made a mess]

This is my html page with some jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Responsive Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/princstyle.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  <!-- hide the secondary navigation bar -->
  $("#socialnav").hide();

  $("#social-icon").click(
    function(){
        $("#socialnav").toggle();
    })
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- header -->
    <div class="big">
        <h1 class="big-font">
            Responsive Website
        </h1>
        <h2 class="medium-font">
            trytrytrytrytry
        </h2>
        <ul id="generalnav" class="nav big centered-content dark-background">
            <li><img id="social-icon" alt="social_icon" src="img/social.png"></li><!--
            --><li><img alt="sections_icon" src="img/sections.png"></li><!--
            --><li><img alt="javascript_section_icon" src="img/javascripticon.png"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="socialnav" class="nav big centered-content dark-background">
            <li><img alt="social_icon" src="img/social.png"></li><!--
            --><li><img alt="sections_icon" src="img/sections.png"></li><!--
            --><li><img alt="javascript_section_icon" src="img/javascripticon.png"></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for helping me! This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxqk4/) (The only icon that works (toggles) is the left one).

Answer (score 2):

First you should nest the lists, as the second one is a child of the first one.

```
    <ul id="generalnav" class="nav big centered-content dark-background">
        <li><img id="social-icon" alt="social_icon" src="img/social.png">
            <ul id="socialnav" class="nav big centered-content dark-background">
                <li><img alt="social_icon" src="img/social.png"></li>
                <li><img alt="sections_icon" src="img/sections.png"></li>
                <li><img alt="javascript_section_icon" src="img/javascripticon.png"></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li><img alt="sections_icon" src="img/sections.png"></li>
        <li><img alt="javascript_section_icon" src="img/javascripticon.png"></li>
    </ul>
```

Then you can do things like: (You don't need any Javascript.)

```
    #generalnav li ul { display:none; }
    #generalnav li:hover ul { display:block; }
```

This also allows you to use relative positioning for the linking image.

Comment: Thank you, it seems a great solution. I can't try it at this moment, but I'll give you a feedback as soon as possible.